# Accessing the restforce collection to retrive data in a ruby script

Tags: ruby, restforce

This seems to be a basic thing, but kind of not sure on how to access the data from restforce::collection

```
require 'restforce'

##set up the connection  part here

accounts = client.query('select Id, EventType, Logdate from EventLogFile where LogDate = Last_n_Days:2')
p accounts
```

the accounts object return as restforce::collection like this:

```
#<Restforce::Collection:0x00000002197218 @client=#<Restforce::Data::Client @options={:api_version=>"41.0", :username=>"sfdc.dev", :password=>"somepass!", :security_token=>nil, :client_id=>"3MVG9A2kN3Bn1XgTalsb2qZ0e7r9tzLavy7o_V7AAQG7jKctPLq.qDq", :client_secret=>"87623", :host=>"login.salesforce.com", :oauth_token=>"DIZcbAJBBdKtF67Vm3pBI1vasRBp41PQpDCz2yfghnqwXYpyvcecLvpUx", :refresh_token=>nil, :instance_url=>"https://myorg.my.salesforce.com", :cache=>nil, :authentication_retries=>3, :compress=>nil, :mashify=>nil, :timeout=>nil, :adapter=>:net_http, :proxy_uri=>nil, :authentication_callback=>nil, :ssl=>{}, :request_headers=>nil, :logger=>#<Logger:0x00000002158158 @level=0, @progname=nil, @default_formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x000000021580e0 @datetime_format=nil>, @formatter=nil, @logdev=#<Logger::LogDevice:0x00000002158068 @shift_period_suffix=nil, @shift_size=nil, @shift_age=nil, @filename=nil, @dev=#<IO:<STDOUT>>, @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Thread::Mutex:0x00000002158798>>>, :log_level=>:debug}>, @raw_page={"totalSize"=>2, "done"=>true, "records"=>[{"attributes"=>{"type"=>"Account", "url"=>"/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Account/001i000002EF7iDAAT"}, "Id"=>"001i000002EF7iDAAT", "Name"=>"Sterlidge Pty Ltd", "AccountNumber"=>nil}, {"attributes"=>{"type"=>"Account", "url"=>"/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Account/001i000002EF7iEAAT"}, "Id"=>"001i000002EF7iEAAT", "Name"=>"Sherwood Gem Pty Ltd", "AccountNumber"=>nil}]}>
```

How can i retrieve the values for say like `:oauth_token` ? doing something like
`accounts[:oauth_token]`, throws an exception

```
undefined method `[]' for #<Restforce::Collection:0x000000010ead70> (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: I've never used that API, but it looks like you would expect to find `:oauth_token` on `client` not `accounts`. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i am trying to retrieve the `:oauth_token`

Comment: How did you instantiate `client`? You might try something like `accounts.client.options[:oauth_token]`.

Comment: i have tried that, ``<main>': undefined method `client' for #<Restforce::Collection:0x00000000a26e80> (NoMethodError)` .. this gem uses something call hashie::Mash https://github.com/intridea/hashie/tree/v1.2.0   and so may be the retrieval is weird

Comment: How about using client directly, as thats how you get accounts anyway. eg: `client.options[:oauth_token]`. API: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/restforce/Restforce.

Comment: yeah!!! that did it

Comment: pls put that as the answer and i will accept it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162932/discussion-between-ok999-and-jacob-vanus).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [API](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/restforce/Restforce) you can get the `oauth_token` from the `client` like so:

```
client.options[:oauth_token]
```